# Resultados de las categorías erróneos en Google Places

Tags: javascript, google-places

estoy intentando que google me devuelva los lugares cercanos a una dirección concreta. Todo funciona bien a excepción que los resultados de las categorías no son demasiado correctos. Si por ejemplo pides que te devuelva restaurantes, te devuelve restaurantes, más tiendas, más algún supermercado...
He hecho las peticiones mediante category y keyword ( ya que con category a veces no devuelve casi ningún resultado). Si lo busco por google los resultados que devuelve son más fiables que los que encuentro por el google places, así que entiendo que se ha de poder mejorar la búsqueda. 
¿Hay alguna manera de que devuelva un resultado más exacto? ¿ alguien se ha encotrado con el mismo problema, y ha encontrado una solución, u otra api que de un resultado más fiable.

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Podrías compartir tu código? Que has intentado, como lo has hecho en el caso de dar errores mostrar cual es el error. Echa un vistazo al [tour] y [ask] para mejorar tus preguntas

Comment: ¿Cómo estás usando la API de Google Places?

Comment: Disculpar, he tenido que abandonar el proyecto. Gracias de todas maneras.